# Setting Up virtualenv with python2.6

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm setting up a `virtualenv`, but it seems to be using python2.5 by default.

I'm using this command

```
virtualenv newenv --no-site-packages -p python
```

because the python found on my path is python2.6. I believe this to be true because when I type `python` and go into the shell, it tells me it's 2.6. When I create the `virtualenv` with the above command and launch the shell, it tells me I'm in 2.5.

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: No, I don't see this behaviour. Why not just specify the 2.6 binary in your -p option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this as the location of python works on OSX 10.6

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python`